# Getting a Type Error while integrating FB SDK in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I managed to integrate Facebook in ionic successfully . Facebook Login is working fine . Now i want to use Facebook log Events,i am trying like below

Here is my Code

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() 
{  $cordovaFacebook.AppEvents.logEvent($cordovaFacebook.AppEvents.EventNames.COMPLETED_REGISTRATION);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'logEvent' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to integrate Facebook Sdk and successfully implement Facebook analytics and login in ionic .
For this we have to move a file under the name facebook-native present in /plugin/Cordova-plugin/facebook4 to www/lib and rename it as facebookConnectPlugin.js.

Also update index.html by giving link to facebookConnectPlugin.js and by creating one div element of id fb-root.